# How to add only values at hashtable

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashtable

I'm asked to create a

`Hashtable <Client, List<Article>> sellings`

, and then, there is a method that I should create

`registerSellings(Client k ,Article a)`

and the exercises says that if a `Client k`, exist on the table `sellings`, then the article will be added at the selling table as a value, so I did it this way,

```
 if(sellings.containsKey(k)) {
 ....
 }
```

but what should I write inside if block, to add the value to the current existing key, if the client doesn't exist as a key in the selling table, then add it to the sellings table including a new list of articles as a value, to which first add the sold article.

Comment: Did you notice that map value is a `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the client exists, just [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) the article to his list. If he doesn't create a new list and add to it:

```
if (sellings.containsKey(k)) {
    sellings.get(k).add(a);
} else {
    List<Article> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(a);
    sellings.put(k, list);
}
```

Note that Java 8's [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) would make this whole block go away, and produce much more elegant code:

```
sellings.computeIfAbsent(k, s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(a);
```

Comment: Thank u so much mate!!